# Export LMER result from R to Excel?

Tags: r, excel, export

I'm a beginner in using R. I only did one day formation to learn how to launch basics statistical analysis.
I need to do a database which contains all the results for each variables with the differents statistical models. [Exemple of data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2r7v.png)

Because I have plenty variables I would prefer to spend a day to find a solution to export the dates in a .xlsx than copy and paste (for this protocol and the next one).

For the moment, I'm trying to find the solution for the null model. Example:

```
m1a <- lmer(RPE ~ (1|Id), data=IMPACT_Longi, REML=FALSE)
summary(m1a)
```

The results with summary are working with all my variables[results example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7crW.png)

From this point I spent my day to find a solution:

- Copy and past in excel and then change the shape of the datas by using "convert"
- Try to build my own excel table from R
- Use  sink() to export as .txt abd csv which the same result than copy and paste
- Use tidy() from broom which doesn't work

  tidy(m1a)
  Erreur : No tidy method for objects of class lmerModLmerTest

If anyone could help me... Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are many packages that facilitate writing to excel files. The ones I used in the past are `openxlsx` (works great for .xlsx format) and `xlsx` (which I wouldn't recommend due to its Java dependency). Also, don't use `sink` to write a .csv but `write.csv`. And finally: There seem to be (at least) two distinct issues: How to get results from `lmer` into table/data.frame form and how to write to xlsx/csv...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096692/getting-lmer-output-to-word-excel

Comment: convert and elements from the list into a vector and do apply or lapply for different variables. You could get a perfect solution by sharing a reproducible sample. Use dput(head(data))